# Moving Ubuntu VM to SSD

Tags: azure, ssd

I decided to move my VM from A4_V2 to D11_V2 Promo because the D11_V2 offers SSD. However when I moved the VM, I don't see any difference in Azure Portal when I'm checking the disk:

```
Type
STANDARD
Size (GiB)
100
Estimated performance 
IOPS LIMIT  500
THROUGHPUT LIMIT (MB/S) 60
```

I'm expecting 100GB SSD with 6000 IOPS.

Server location: North Europe

How can I move the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating new VM with Premium SSD and then moving configuration and files from old VM using rsync.

Answer (score 2):

Resizing the VM doesn't covert the disk. If you're using managed disks, the process is very easy:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-disk-storage

If you're using standard storage, then you have a few additional steps to go:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-migration-to-premium-storage

You can also convert from unmanaged to managed disk and then easily convert to SSD.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks